# Using text variable to fill text field, how?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to use a variable to fill a text field. It's possible to do this with Capybara? Edit: Now with code and failure too, sorry guys.

```
  describe 'test' do

it 'test0' do
    visit 'https://www.submarino.com.br/'

    livro = page.first('img[alt~="Livro"]').click

    nome = page.find('#product-name-default').text
    puts nome

    autor = find('table tbody tr', text: 'Autor').text
    puts autor

    isbn = find('table tbody tr', text: 'ISBN-13').text
    puts isbn

end

it 'teste1' do 
    visit 'https://www.americanas.com.br/'

    fill_in 'h_search-input',   with: isbn  **# <- here is the error**
    click_button 'h_search-btn'

end

it 'teste2' do 
    visit 'https://www.amazon.com.br/'
end
end
```

HTML element

```
<input id="h_search-input" class="src-input" type="text" name="conteudo" placeholder="tem tuuudo, pode procurar :)" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" value="">
```

Failure get:

```
Failures:

1) teste teste1
 Failure/Error: fill_in 'h_search-input',   with: isbn

 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `isbn' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Teste "teste1" (./spec/teste_spec.rb:23)>
 # ./spec/teste_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Generally you want to fill a text field with a string so `name = "129923823184"` - other than that what you're doing is exactly correct (assuming `text_field` matches the name, id, placeholder, or associated label text of the text field.  If it's not working for you edit your question and provide the exact error you're getting, along with the html of the element you're trying to fill in.

Comment: Omg, so the method is correct? I'm shocked hahahahaha. Well, I edit and post the entire code. Thanks again Thomas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests are isolated from one another, and are also separate methods. You can't assign a local variable in one method and access it in another because they're not the same scope - https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/.  You can however access instance variables from before blocks (because they're assigned on the test instance).  You either need to get the value inside the test block where you use it or if you want that value in multiple tests you can use a `before(:each)` or `before(:all)` depending on whether you want it calculated for every test or just once (the just once is generally not a great idea because it can lead to test coupling if the value is changed inside a test)

```
describe 'test' do
  before(:each) do
    visit 'https://www.submarino.com.br/'

    livro = page.first('img[alt~="Livro"]').click

    nome = page.find('#product-name-default').text
    puts nome

    autor = find('table tbody tr', text: 'Autor').text
    puts autor

    @isbn = find('table tbody tr', text: 'ISBN-13').text
    puts @isbn
  end

  it 'teste1' do 
    visit 'https://www.americanas.com.br/'

    fill_in 'h_search-input',   with: @isbn
    click_button 'h_search-btn'
    # Add whatever expectation you are testing for here
  end

  it 'teste2' do 
    visit 'https://www.amazon.com.br/'

    ... # do something using @isbn
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for ur hints and thanks for that scope link! It worked! I just learning by myself so it's kinda hard sometimes hahahahaah